# SQL import/create columns in SMILE chemical structures

Tags: sql, csv, types

We try to import a csv file where the first column includes chemical structures (SMILE) like this

```
 c1cccc(c12)n(C)c(c2)CN(C)C(=O)c(c3)ccc(c34)NCC(=O)N(C4)C,14-BENZODIAZEPINEDERIV.4_145,1
 c1cccc(c12)n(C)c(c2)CN(C)C(=O)c(c3)ccc(c34)N[C@H](C(=O)N(C4)C)CC(=O)OC,14-BENZODIAZEPINEDERIV.3_146,1
```

Here is the code in SQL

```
--Define Table
CREATE TABLE Amide_actives_test
(Structure VARCHAR(40),
Name VARCHAR(40),
Active INT)
GO

--Import Data from CSV

BULK 
INSERT Amide_actives_test
FROM 'C:\Amide_actives.csv'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'   --Use to shift the control to next row
)
GO
--Check the content of the table
SELECT * FROM Amide_actives_test
GO
```

The following error message will pop out:

```
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 1 (Name).
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
...repeating the previous 2 lines 10 times....
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not    give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Apparently there is a problem of SQL to read the first column in "Structure VARCHAR(40)".  I have tried all the string types (CHAR,VARCHAR.NCHAR,NVARCHAR,NTEXT,TEXT) and none of them works.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848814.aspx

There is one way to solve this issue is to purchase another customized MySQL module from DayLight. However, 1. it costs 2. it doesn't support SQL

http://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/pgsql/daycart_pg_search.html

May I know if any SQL guru has SQL solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Your column definition for `Structure` and `Name` is for 40 characters (`VARCHAR(40)`) but your data in the `Structure` column in the first row is 56 long, and even longer on the second row - thus the truncation error. Try redefining your table as `NVARCHAR(255)` for both columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem is `Structure VARCHAR(40)` `varchar length` is lesser than the input so you got `trucation error`. Try increasing the `varchar length` and check